# Событие после выбора даты в Datepicker

Tags: jquery

Использую эту библиотеку https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default Нужно что бы после выбора даты выполнялось какое нибудь событие, пусть даже обычный Alert. Есть какие нибудь callback функции или как можно решить по другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    onSelect : function(dateText, inst){
        alert(dateText); // Выбранная дата
    }
});
```